# Which is correct, getting cheap day by day or getting cheaper day by day?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which is correct and why?

> memory is getting cheap day by day
>   or 
>   memory is getting cheaper day by day

The original paragraph context is

> Though memory is getting cheap day by day, still there are massive demand for the low memory algorithms for practical problems which need to be run on tiny devices, for example, sensors, GPS systems, mobile hand-sets, small robots, etc.

Comment: “Getting cheaper day by day” is the expression if  you want to convey the   meaning  that every day the price decreases.

Comment: @user159691  actually both are possible (although you're only likely to *hear* the second).   It all depends on whether you want to say that X is becoming *less expensive than it was* or *objectively inexpensive*.  OP needs to add more detail to the question.

Comment: Please add more detail to this question.  What exactly do you want to say?  Both are possible, but mean slightly different things.

Comment: @Andrew - I think that with the time expression, day by day, cheaper is only option. Or you say memory is getting cheap.

Comment: I think by **memory** you mean **computer memory**.

Comment: idiomatic usage: "getting X [comparative adjective" by the day: getting richer, getting poorer, getting more stupid, getting more intelligent, getting fatter, getting thinner by the day. "getting cheap day by day" is not idiomatic.

Comment: What @Lambie said. Though the offered examples may pass the sniff test grammatically, the overwhelming favorite would still be "getting cheaper by the day."

Comment: @user159691  Yes, that's a good point.  "Day by day" implies an ongoing process, so you're implicitly comparing the current day's value with the previous day's value.

Comment: I disagree that "getting cheap day by day" makes any sense at all. Getting x-comparative is a process. It would be booted by any editor working in English.

Comment: I have added the original paragraph in context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a comparative **cheaper** works with either a progressive change over a period of time or a single, step change.

The use of an adjective **cheap** suggests that some threshold has been crossed: before it was expensive, now it's cheap. The decline in cost could have occurred over a long period of time, but the threshold between expensive and cheap would have happened in a moment.

The use of a continuous tense **getting** and **day by day** both suggest a progressive change without a threshold: this precludes the use of **cheap**, so **cheaper** is the best term to use.